# Why is there no data inside of my database when step debugging my Laravel Sail application?

Tags: laravel, database, debugging, laravel-sail

## Background

I am using PhpStorm to debug a test that creates a database entry. My goal is to set a breakpoint, then inspect the database manually.

I have confirmed this so far:

- Step debugging is properly configured
- Can connect via a forwarding port set up in `docker-compose.yml` (Fig. 1)
- Laravel reports the entry exists in the database (Fig. 2)

## Relevant Code

The star below indicates my breakpoint.

```php
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\LazilyRefreshDatabase;
...

class ObfuscatedTestClass extends TestCase
{
  use LazilyRefreshDatabase;

...

/** @test */
public function obfuscated_test_name() {
    Queue::fake();
    ObfuscatedModelName::factory()->create();
*    Queue::assertPushed(SyncLeaseWithAccountingApp::class);
}
```

## Hypotheses

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how databases are handled during these tests. I know Laravel has the ability to use database transactions to speed up tests, but I expect it to be modifying the database here when I'm using `LazilyRefreshDatabase`. Why else would I need to set up a database for testing?

## Figures

Figure 1
[image: Successful database connection]

Figure 2
[image: A database entry exists]

Comment: What is configured in the `phpunit.xml` file? Usually it uses a `sqlite` database for testing (`<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>` & `<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>`) but you're trying to connect to a mysql server.

Comment: @pmcpimentel shoot! I really thought this was on the right track but it appears that I don't have either of those defined in `phpunit.xml`. I used the debugger to check `$_ENV` in a test and this is the only value that is set: `DB_HOST = "mysql_test"` (the name of my Docker container holding the test DB).

Comment: added the 2 lines to the `phpunit.xml` file (inside the `<php>` tags)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same boat all day, I also suspected transactions as a likely cause.

Then I came to realize all that was needed is to refresh the database connection when stopped at a breakpoint.

I'm not sure if this will be helpful to anyone but I thought I should answer because my situation is so similar to OP's - also running Docker and PhpStorm.

We're typically not in the habit of refreshing the db connection on a regular basis so it's easy to overlook.

EDIT:
To tag a little bit more onto my answer from earlier.. The data will persist if your test does not wipe it which can be useful. You can then tinker with that data by creating a file named ".env.testing" & setting APP_ENV=testing. Then run tinker like so: php artisan tinker --env=testing